# Rails: OAuth accounts with something other than user using oauth_plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, google-oauth

I'm setting up an OAuth consumer rails app using a gem called oauth_plugin (https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin)

On my app users have access to multiple projects and each project needs to be able to connect to a different Google Analytics account using OAuth (so I can pull stats for each one).

The default set up for oauth_plugin is for OAuth tokens to be associated with users. I've tried to change it to be associated with projects by changing the models and controllers but if I do that I get this error when trying to connect the service:

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in OauthConsumersController#show**

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: consumer_tokens.user_id: 
SELECT  "consumer_tokens".* FROM "consumer_tokens"  WHERE "consumer_tokens"."type" IN ('GoogleToken') AND "consumer_tokens"."user_id" = '1' LIMIT 1
```

There's nothing in my controllers like this so I'm guessing it's in the plugin somewhere. Does anyone know how I could get around this?

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use that plugin insted of OmniAuth https://github.com/intridea/omniauth ?

Comment: No particular reason, just seemed like the best one when I Googled for one.
OmniAuth looks pretty good. Have you used it before?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion is the best, has great integration with a lot of SN, and I haven't use it with Google yet but it is amazing while working with Facebook and Twitter. Check this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?autoplay=true